# Converting VB6 AES Rijndael Block Cipher to C# by Phil Fresle

Tags: c#, encryption, vbscript, asp-classic

I am converting a classic asp application to C#, and would like to be able to decrypt strings in c#  that were originally encrypted in classic asp. the classic asp code is [here](http://www.frez.co.uk/vb6.aspx), and the c# code is [here](http://www.frez.co.uk/csharp.aspx). The problem that i am facing is that the signatures of the Encrypt and Decrypt methods in asp vs C# are different. here is my asp code for decrypting, which wraps the decrypt code.

```
Function AESDecrypt(sCypher)
 if sCypher <> "" then

    Dim bytIn()
    Dim bytOut
    Dim bytPassword()
    Dim lCount
    Dim lLength
    Dim sTemp
    Dim sPassword 
    sPassword = "My_Password"

    lLength = Len(sCypher)
    ReDim bytIn(lLength/2-1)
    For lCount = 0 To lLength/2-1
        bytIn(lCount) = CByte("&H" & Mid(sCypher,lCount*2+1,2))
    Next
    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword,lCount,1)))
    Next

    bytOut = DecryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)  //' this is the problem child

    lLength = UBound(bytOut) + 1
    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
        sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytOut(lCount))
    Next

    AESDecrypt = sTemp
 End if 
End Function
```

However, in c# i am struggling to convert this function because the c# equivalent of DecryptData has more params

```
public static byte[] DecryptData(byte[] message, byte[] password, 
            byte[] initialisationVector, BlockSize blockSize, 
            KeySize keySize, EncryptionMode cryptMode)
        {...}
```

what values can i use for initialisationVector, blockSize, keySize, cryptMode so as to be able to decrypt the same way the classic asp code does.

Comment: That entirely depends on what `DecryptData()` does.  However, you are probably using ECB, which is not secure.

Comment: thanx, DecryptData is both in the classic asp and c# versions of the code, i could paste it here but it is quite a long piece of code, it can be found in the links that i posted. My biggest challenge is that the DecryptData function has different signatures yet it is from the same author. I would like to migrate from classic asp to c# and would like to slowly retire asp code, hence the encryption must produce the same result in c# as it does in asp

Comment: So you're asking us to tell you what mode your function uses, without showing us the function?

Comment: Found the solution for encrypting here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14674957/523714

Comment: Looks like VBScript, not VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Phil Fresle's C# Rijndael  implementation, you can use the following code to have successfully decrypt a value that was encrypted with Phil's ASP/VBScript version.

You can read my answer about encrypting here: [Password encryption/decryption between classic asp and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679296/password-encryption-decryption-between-classic-asp-and-asp-net/14674957)

```
    public string DecryptData(string encryptedMessage, string password)
    {
        if (encryptedMessage.Length % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

        byte[] byteArr = new byte[encryptedMessage.Length / 2];
        for (int index = 0; index < byteArr.Length; index++)
        {
            string byteValue = encryptedMessage.Substring(index * 2, 2);
            byteArr[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }


        byte[] result = Rijndael.DecryptData(
            byteArr,
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password),
            new byte[] { }, // Initialization vector
            Rijndael.BlockSize.Block256, // Typically 128 in most implementations
            Rijndael.KeySize.Key256,
            Rijndael.EncryptionMode.ModeECB // Rijndael.EncryptionMode.ModeCBC
        );

        return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
    }
```

Most default implementations will use a key size of **128**, **192**, or **256** bits. A block size at **128** bits is standard. Although some implementations allow block sizes other than 128 bits, changing the block size will just add another item into the mix to cause confusion when trying to get data encrypted in one implementation to properly decrypt in another.

### UPDATE

Turns out I was wrong about one piece here; the `EncryptionMode` should be set as `EncryptionMode.ModeECB`, not `EncryptionMode.ModeCBC`. "ECB" is less secure (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher) because it doesn't cycle like CBC does, but that is how it was implemented in the VB version of the encryption.

Interestingly enough, using CBC on an ECB encrypted value WILL work for the first handful of bytes up until a certain point (i'd imagine this has to do with the block size) at which point the remainder of the value is mangled. You can see this particularly clearly when encrypting a long-ish string in the VB version and decrypting it with the code I posted above with a mode of `EncryptionMode.ModeECB`